# Finding reporting data using CriteriaBuilder

Tags: glassfish, eclipselink, criteria-api

I have a table table from which I need to extract reporting data. I've created the following class to contain the results. I've removed the constructors for brevity.

```
public class BillingEventDateCount {
    private String date;
    private Integer count;
}
```

I've then started with a criteria query which should populate a list of the results. Honestly, I have no idea how to do this... I want to implement the following query.

```
SELECT date(`create_timestamp`) as 'date',SUM(price) as 'count' FROM billingEvent groupby date(`create_timestamp`);
```

I've started with the following criteria query but have no idea how to do this.

```
    public List<BillingEventDateCount> findBillingEventByBillingServiceDailyTotals(Integer billingServiceId, Date startDateObj, Date endDateObj, String msisdn, String refNum) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery = cb.createQuery();
    Root billingSummary = criteriaQuery.from(BillingEvent.class);
    criteriaQuery.select(cb.construct(BillingEventDateCount.class,billingSummary.get("date"),billingSummary.get("count"))).groupBy(billingSummary.get("date"));
    return em.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
}
```

Can anyone please help? I really can't make heads or tails of this.

Comment: 1. You have (I think) wrong design decision, and append next & next & next decision. 2. Cant believe this code can  compile and meet elementar of Java, JPA and others

Comment: I agree that it isn't right, I didn't claim that it was. I showed what I'm trying to achieve in SQL and my lame attempt to get it right in JPA. I was hoping for some helpful advice, not "you did it wrong".